# PHP. MySQL. Cравнение

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Не работает код

```
if ($enter_login == mysqli_query($mysql_connect_link, "SELECT login FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE ID='$enter_id' "))
```

При таком коде

```
$m = mysqli_query($mysql_connect_link, "SELECT login FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE ID='$enter_id' ");
echo $m;
```

Выдает ошибку

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in /var/www/test.site/public_html/example.php on line 8

а код

```
print_r($m);
```

выдает

> mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 1 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 1 [type] => 0 )

Ну с этого понятно, что запрос выдает не то что в ячейке login

Как его изменить чтобы if работал.

***Скажу так нужно чтобы запрос мне выдал то, что написано в ячейке.***

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе

Comment: Я этим и занимался ))

Comment: `if ($enter_login == mysqli_query(` - тут надо писать `TRUE === mysqli_query(...`, а не `$enter_login ==` ......вот примеры в доках даже: http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php#refsect1-mysqli.query-examples..........`Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string` - это потому, что ты пытаешься `mysqli_result` выводить через `echo`.........`выдает

mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 1 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 1 [type] => 0 )` - это потому, что к `$m` надо еще применить [mysqli_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

Comment: т.е. чтобы посмотреть введенный логин совпадает с логином из db с ID = 1 нужно в if писать `if($enter_login === mysqli_query(...)`

Comment: нет.... там должно быть `TRUE === mysqli_query(`..............нужно в начале выбрать `mysqli_result`, который возвращает `mysqli_query`, сравнить его на `TRUE` чтоб убедиться, что запрос прошел корректно, затем выбрать результат через `mysqli_fetch_assoc` и только потом взять из полученного массива логин и сравнить с `$enter_login`

Comment: я прочел не mysqli_fetch_assoc а mysqli_fetch_row
И большое спасибо без вашего комментария я бы не нашел ответ)

Comment: ну при выборке одного лишь значения роли особой нет `mysqli_fetch_assoc` или `mysqli_fetch_row`. А в целом при выборке целой строки со значениями (или массива строк) гораздо лучше будет ориентироваться на имена, нежели на индексы 0,1,2,3 и т.д...........И да, почитай про подготовленные запросы http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php ...... это очень важно для безопасности. сейчас, не смотря на использование `mysqli` у тебя она (безопасность) отсутствует

Comment: Спасибо большое я обязательно прочитаю ))

Comment: Это для курсача я пытаюсь быстро его закончить так как осталось 5 дней а я только начал и притом я новичок в веб программировании. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как `ID` у меня PRIMARY KEY то результат команды

```
SELECT login
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE ID = $enter_id;
```

будет одна ячейка.
Для того чтобы изъять строку из этой ячейки можно воспользоваться функцией

```
mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query(mysqli_connect(...), ...));
```

т.е. для моего `if` код будет иметь вид

```
$array_enter_login = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($mysql_connect_link, "SELECT login FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE ID='$enter_id' "));
if ($enter_login == $array_enter_login[login])
{
   echo "Yes!";
}
```